# Need storage locker for cell phone because US consulate in São Paulo does not permit one

Tags: passports, cellphones, consulates, sao-paulo

Sadly the consulate website simply states you can't enter with a cellphone and will need to "make arrangements" to stash your phone.  Does anybody know if there is a nearby locker to put my phone in?

Answer (score 1):

The German consulate in Boston has the same rule, which is rather impractical. So far I've been able to negotiate my way around it: Leave it at security or show them that it's turned off. Sometimes, they don't even ask.

Maybe you can call the consulate and ask. People on the phone tend to be more accommodating then websites.

Comment: US Consulates don't typically negotiate with non-diplomats.

Comment: @CharlesSpencer: in my personal experience they do. A lot. Consistency and predictable do not seem to factor high on their list of virtue and "making it up as we go along" seems to be the standard operating procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a service provided by the Consulate in São Paulo for this. On the other hand, there is a bunch of people providing these services around the Consulate. It is important to say that normally is people that leave around there or small stores. It is not 100% safe, but also, I never heard any problem.

Another option is to use a locker at the airport or bus station. If you will be in a hotel, you also can use their locker.

Comment: the idea is avoid a trip back to the hotel as I'll already be checked out. Also I want to use Uber.

Comment: There are places outside of Consulate that you can stay your cellphone, pendrive and so on. So, you will find a place, don't worry!
Here is a news (http://sao-paulo.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,vizinhos-de-consulado-lucram-com-guarda-volumes,543628) talking about it (in portuguese). I estimate that you will spend almost R$ 10.